# Change html tag in NSString

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, ipad

For example I have html string:

```
<p>
    <img mce_src="http://example.com/apple.png" src="http://example.com/apple.png" width="512" height="512" style="">
    <br mce_bogus="1">
</p>
```

How can I change this properties: `width="512" height="512"`to for example: `width="123" height="123"`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go with regular expressions and try the [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) library.

```
NSString *regex = @"(=\"[0-9]+\")";

NSString *replaced = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regex usingBlock:^NSString *(NSInteger captureCount, NSString * const capturedStrings[captureCount], const NSRange capturedRanges[captureCount], volatile BOOL * const stop) {
  return(@"123");
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Your example with the html in `htmlString`

```
htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"width=\"512\""
                                     withString:@"width=\"123\""];
```

**EDIT:**

Using regex replacement (not tested):

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.*width=\").*?(\".*?height=\").*?(\".*)"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:htmlString
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [htmlString length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"$1<insert width here>$2<insert height here>$3"];
```

reference:
[NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: he problem is that I do not know what the width and height value at the pictures .. It can be 511 or 246 or 143 and other

Comment: Search by regular expression then, but beware of doing this on an HTML string, as it is pretty fragile (maybe the format of the HTML string will change?)

Comment: in the pattern could put this, so as to change only the piece of interest if present @"(width=\").*?\"", and then instead of $1$2, put the new value.

Answer (score 0):

just take your html in string and Make a function using for loop and on the occurrence of  **width** and **height** count its length and  location and then replace this with new data......i did this...

Answer (score 0):

add new width and height property inside of img tag

```
NSError *regexError = nil;
    NSRegularExpressionOptions options = 0;

    NSString *pattern = @"(img)";
    NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:options error:&regexError];

    wihoutWidth = [expression stringByReplacingMatchesInString:wihoutWidth
                                                       options:0
                                                         range:NSMakeRange(0,wihoutWidth.length)
                                                  withTemplate:@"$1 width=293 height=150"];
    return wihoutWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

How to just replace the width using this code ? And also I want to insert a string or a number in $1

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.*width=\").*?(\".*?height=\").*?(\".*)"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:htmlString
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [htmlString length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"$1$2$3"];